# Is it fine to Add a reference of Microsoft.Visual Basic and use the functions in C#

Tags: c#, vba, vb6-migration

A general question. Is it considered ok to add a reference of `Microsoft.Visualbasic` and use in C# or will it slow down our website?

VB has functions like `Strings.Format` etc.

I am right now converting a hell lot of code from VBA to C# and am short on time.

Comment: Reflector & ILSpy (an open source offering) can decompile an assembly and give you the results in either Vb/Net or C#. Might speed up your code port, that said ILSpy doesn't handle lambds so well, not so sure about Reflector.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - I don't believe Reflector or ILSpy can decompile VBA/VB6, as this is what the OP is porting.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is fine.

The assemblies in `Microsoft.VisualBasic` are CLS compliant and are safe to use with any .NET language.

Just be aware that some functions are subtly different between VBA, VB6 and VB.NET.

Comment: my senior said it slows down the website thats why wanted to ask the question thanks

Comment: They're 'just' assemblies that implement whatever logic they do. There's no differerence between these assemblies and any other assembly that you'd use. You should test their performance characteristics but that'd be true for any other assembly.

Comment: @vini - Only to the extent that they are additional assemblies that need to be loaded. This, however, is true for any library being used. In general, what your senior is saying is incorrect.

Comment: so what you advice me to use Microsoft.VisualBasic reference or not?

Comment: @vini - It is up to you. It will not slow down the website and may speed up your porting efforts. However, your senior said no and I can't tell you what to do about _that_.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you're fine to use these methods, but you should be aware that the equivalent code in C# will be very simple and easy to write.

Fo example, `Strings.Format` is almost exactly the same as the more widely used `String.Format` available on the main .NET String class (VB or C#).

`String.Chr` will result in the same as `(char)intValue`

Answer (score 0):

If you are short on time then you think you can't do the work properly then don't commit to the work. Ask for more time or resources. But I would say don't use the MS.VB reference. Use C# or VB.Net which ever you are using.